# UITextField displaying "Optional("")" before input

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift2, option-type

I am currently in the process of converting my iOS app to Swift 2 and ran into this.  I have a text field that uses the numeric keyboard.  When I switched to Swift 2, when I type in a number, lets say 5, it will show up as `Optional("")5` in the text field.  I'm pretty sure it is because of something in an extension.

```
extension GroupViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var shouldProcess = false
        var shouldMoveToNextField = false

        let insertStringLength = string.characters.count
        if insertStringLength == 0 {
            shouldProcess = true
        } else {
            if textField.text!.characters.count == 0 {
                shouldProcess = true
            }
        }

        if shouldProcess {
            var newString = textField.text

            if newString!.characters.count == 0 {
                newString = "\(newString)\(string)"
                shouldMoveToNextField = true
            } else {
                if insertStringLength > 0 {
                    newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
                } else {
                    newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "")
                }
            }

            textField.text = newString!

            if shouldMoveToNextField {
                let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)

                if let nextResponder = nextResponder {
                    nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
                } else {
                    dismissKeyboard()
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code that you are working with

Comment: Sorry, just did. @ksa_coder

Comment: highlight which part we are looking at specifically.

Comment: It has to do with newString, because if I change the line `textField.text = newString!` to `textField.text = 5` then it works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code:

```
 var newString = textField.text

            if newString!.characters.count == 0 {
                newString = "\(newString)\(string)"
                shouldMoveToNextField = true
            }
```

Change...

```
newString = "\(newString)\(string)"
```

to....

```
newString = "\(string)"
```

Comment: @lagoon before the statement textField.text = newString!, can you do print(newString) and tell us the value

Comment: `Optional("Optional(\"\")5")`

Comment: change newString = "\(newString)\(string)" to newString = "\(newString)"..what you get?

Comment: Ah, fixed it.  I changed `newString = "\(newString)\(string)"` to `newString = "\(string)"`

Comment: great...I will update the answer so that it can help others

Comment: Change the updated answer to \(string) instead though